# Zend Framework 2 SocalNick / ScnSocialAuth module

Tags: zend-framework2

I am getting following error message while I am trying to login via facebook using this (https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth) module of ZF 2. Could anyone say what can be the solution ??

Error message

Auth event was stopped without a response. Got "NULL" instead

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error. To solve it, I used this explanation : https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth/issues/91

So just remove this line into your composer.json **"zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master",** or **"zf-commons/zfc-user": "0.1.*",** (that was my error)

and change it to this **"zf-commons/zfc-user": "0.1.2",**

ps: don't forget to remove into the database the user and the provider, and clear the browser session.